# How can I apply drag and drop functionality (from local file browser to chonky file browser)? - Typescript, React, Chonky.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

can anyone show me how to properly apply drag and drop functionality (from local file browser to chonky file browser). I'm using React Typescript with Chonky.io library.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import {
  FileBrowser,
  FileContextMenu,
  FileList,
  FileNavbar,
  FileToolbar,
} from 'chonky';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd';

const FileBrowser = ({
  darkMode = false,
  i18n = 'defaultLocale',
  disableDragAndDrop = true,
}: IFileRepositoryProps) => {
 return <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <FileBrowser
              files={files}
              folderChain={folderChain}
              darkMode={darkMode}
              i18n={i18n}
              disableDefaultFileActions={true} //to remove default file actions and replace with customized ones
              fileActions={fileActions}
              onFileAction={handleFileCallback}
              iconComponent={customChonkyIcon}
              disableDragAndDrop={disableDragAndDrop}
            >
              <ThemeProvider theme={overrideStyles}>
                <FileNavbar />
                <FileToolbar />
                <FileList />
                <FileContextMenu />
              </ThemeProvider>
            </FileBrowser>
          </DndProvider>
}
```

This is the portion of code I've come up with but now the drag and drop within the chonky file browser is not working anymore. Would really appreciate your help with this. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? When you click on an element and drag, do any errors show up? If not, place a breakpoint that will trigger when you attempt to drag an element.

Comment: Hi, there is no error in the console, I tried adding a breakpoint that will trigger when I attempt to drag an element but I found out that it is for dragging and dropping within the chonky file browser and the drag and drop from local browser to chonky file browser is still not working. Thanks for quick response by the way :)